# useReducer typescript: State Type

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

How to do the state type when implementing the reducer? I have properties and functions.

```
export interface State {
  form: boolean;
  errorForm: boolean;
  projects: ProjectI[];
  project: ProjectI;
  showFormFn(): void;
  getProjectsFn(): void;
  addProjectFn(project: ProjectI): void;
  showErrorFn(): void;
  currentProjectFn(projectId: string): void;
  deleteProjectFn(projectId: string): void;
}
```

But I'm having trouble using the hook and trying to initialize the state. What would be the correct way to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to implement it in a classic sort of way:

```
interface ProjectI {
    id: string;
}

export interface State {
    form: boolean;
    errorForm: boolean;
    projects: ProjectI[];
    project: ProjectI;
    showFormFn(): void;
    getProjectsFn(): void;
    addProjectFn(project: ProjectI): void;
    showErrorFn(): void;
    currentProjectFn(projectId: string): void;
    deleteProjectFn(projectId: string): void;
}

type Actions = { type: 'addProject', payload: ProjectI } | { type: 'setProject', payload: ProjectI } | { type: 'error' }

function reducer(state: State, action: Actions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'addProject':
            return { ...state, projects: state.projects.concat(action.payload) };
        case 'setProject':
            return { ...state, project: action.payload };
        case 'error':
            return { ...state, errorForm: true };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMBK6AmyDG6UcAvnAGZQQhwDkU6AhvjLQNwBQHwAdjEeWbo4ABSoArdCwCSiDnAVxgOAFxxUMKLwDmnEl3QAPSLCV8BQuAGUYjfnMUVoINQCMIEADZMenR0SooADFnNw9vRl95RTAJKRhUNTEISRkAbQBdPxi4liTcmGlshVQACwgAdxCoECCeAAoASjUANwhlYrhtdBhk1IS6ptb2nE7GHBw%20%20MHYlPj8uZlmuDaO6JLyioBRKEDB5dXR9bh8ZF30PimWGYLpVXVNHQORzpx0b34rmBvFwvuNLQ8bTPNb6DgwACeYGEAEEWMAIDxUHAALyIOCQ6FqWjjSYFWgAGjgYEYEM8EHGC36sjIAB90Zj0NiML18USSWSKfcvjS4PSkIzsQFoLRSFxyMgePDEXAGHhCFB6ho7EzrLZ%20ETmDAETw1HDtYjUI0HIpUBVgDB8KU4PUtTqAHSM40IY6OfCMDB0XFfWgqV2ORQMGBnHjo%203h5Ua4kFRIPFX22b9VD2-CI90wW3SngJ0nk8bGkidN0e4S0Fk%20v0BquynohsMR9XodkFNR2xE5znjUhFxTuz20YVQX3%20qtButIcP2yNNuCD6ouDFQZDCQsjuBvQTITwwSvVxxjqCh6edfRg1NI%20AAYWokB4F3gaKaqIAfCaFOeNHA0tOiThgKgSUtUoMlRFAMGweUiHqOUCCIIkXT3chQgoRhPAwAk1znZDBDQps10TeJYzSJBlGxABmUUSAyDC9wIvJ0VIugKNIGjqzKSp532dESFYqtulZX5UC4pAeLXb0CmEli13Y7ZdmgSTRL3U5zkuCSGmdKS9zeD50C%20BTjhIRpjg4EggA) to show the types that exist within typescript from this.